# Multiple CIImage into a single CIFilter

Tags: swift, core-image

I'm trying to add a image on a video, and then I found [this link](https://forasoft.medium.com/how-to-apply-an-effect-to-a-video-in-ios-bb32f2504036).
I've got two CIimages but not sure how to compile them using CIFilter in Swift. I guess the article is written in obj-c (is it correct?). I'm struggling to find which API correspond to the CIfliter filterWithName in Swift. Could anyone tell me which method should I use in CIFilter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you can use the newish (since iOS 13) protocol-based interface for `CIFilters`:

```swift
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

let filter = CIFilter.blendWithMask()
filter.inputImage = image
filter.backgroundImage = otherImage
filter.maskImage = mask
let output = filter.outputImage
```

Alternatively, you can use the string-based API that is used in the Objective-C code above in Swift as well:

```swift
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask")
filter?.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter?.setValue(otherImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
filter?.setValue(mask, forKey: kCIInputMaskImageKey)
let output = filter.outputImage
```